# how to show a previously hidden div defined by the $_GET function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have recently started coding in PHP and im wondering how i can show a div defined in the adress bar (example: www.yourwebsite.com/index.php?divtoshow=home)

The div is hidden with css, display:none;

then i want it to display the home div

i have tried using jquery, but i cant seem to get the variable to be implamented into the script

I already have the following for when i click the home icon:

```
$(".chome").click(function(){
    $("#home").show(500);
    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Comment: Added that info, im using display:none to hide it from the beginning

Comment: What is generating the URL?  I ask because if it's just a call to your PHP page, then your PHP can generate the markup.  Otherwise, if it's coming from javascript and solely intended to hide the div, why are you going through PHP?

Comment: Is the ID of the supposed to be the value of "divtoshow"? Meaning you would have a div that looks like <div id="home"> already set up in the DOM somewhere?

Comment: @MartinClaesson Ok. I think dbaseman's answer is probably the best solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, get the name from the query string:

```
<?php $divtoshow = $_GET["divtoshow"]; ?>
```

Second, add some JQuery to display the div on page load:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div[id=<?php echo $divtoshow; ?>]").show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: maybe im doing something wrong, but the div doesnt seem to show up upon load

Comment: @MartinClaesson ah, sorry -- I left out the `#` from the JQuery selector... please see above, I fixed it.

Comment: @MartinClaesson do be careful with this if there's sensitive data on your site -- it's begging for a script injection attack.